# For Each Loop with EJS templating

Tags: foreach, ejs

I tried to execute the below lines of code and ended up with the below error message. Any code suggestions to clear this out?

```
<%= kindOfItems.forEach( function (item) { %>
        <div class = "item">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <p>
            <%= item.name %>
            </p>
        </div>
     <%=  }) %>
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in D:\web development\todoList\Todo-List---EJS-master\Todo-List---EJS-master\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with ejs but by the looks of it you are missing a return statement. After a quick google it seems you need to do the following

```
<%= kindOfItems.map( function (item) { %>
        return <div class = "item">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <p>
            <%= item.name %>
            </p>
        </div>
<%=  }) %>
```